# Is it possible to add linked documents to Stereotype?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've tried to add text to a linked document of a Stereotype. Then I export the stereotype into a MDG technology and import on a new project. However, when I create an element of that stereotype I'm not getting the text I added in the linked document.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this should work?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible.

A stereotype is not a template for a new element. You can't define default linked documents in a stereotype.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an add-in that will add the text on element creation. Use the [EA_OnPostNewElement](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/broadcastpostnewelement.html) event for that.